# Пароль отображается как текст в админке (не хэшируется)

Tags: python, django

Есть модель `CustomUser`, наследуемая от `AbstractUser`. При регистрации модели в админке пароль отображается как текст, то есть тип этого поля **text**, а не **password**. Знаю, что эту проблему можно решить если вместе с моделью зарегистрировать класс `ModelAdmin`, в моём случае это будет  `CustomUserAdmin`, наследуемый от `UserAdmin` из `django.contrib.auth.admin`, да при этом пароль будет отображаться корректно, но тогда поля из CustomUser отображаться не будут(как бы зарегистрирована модель `CustomUser`, но отображаться будут только поля модели `User`, при использовании класса наследуемого от выше упомянутого `UserAdmin`). Что с этим делать, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: `ModelAdmin` с определенными `fields`, как именно - смотрите в стандартном django вском `ModelAdmin` юзера

Comment: Спасибо! Я воспользовался опцией fieldsets и указал все нужные поля, при этом наследуясь от UserAdmin. Чет сразу до этого не додумался :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для меня сработала следующая схема

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    '''Extended standard user class '''
    ....

class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User

class Admin(UserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    model = User
    list_display = ('all you need', ...)

admin.site.register(User, Admin)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!